# Passing Array of Strings to another activity to use with ion

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, android-ion

I have `ListView` and i uses [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) library to load images in he `rows` of it, When i tap on any `row` i take the data on the `row` like `TextView` and display it in activity using `Intent`

## Sender Activity

```
// Keys
public static String TITLE = "title";
public static String ARTICLE = "article";
public static String IMG = "img";


Intent passData = new Intent(getContext(), ArticleScreen.class);
       passData.putExtra(TITLE, tv.getText());
       passData.putExtra(ARTICLE, tv2.getText());
       getContext().startActivity(passData);
```

## Receiver Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {

        title = extras.getString(NewsAdapter.TITLE);
        article = extras.getString(NewsAdapter.ARTICLE);

    }
```

Now I have different `ImageView` in every `row` in the `ListView` and i want to display that image in the activity with the text using [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) library, So i have `Array` of `String` named `thumbUrl` contains the `urls` that i want to display in the `row` and `activity`.

## Ion in Sender Activity

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mThumb);

    Ion.with(getContext()).load(thumbUrl[position])
            .withBitmap()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_24dp)
            .intoImageView(iv);
```

So i tried to send that `thumbUrl` `Array` using `Bundle` and `Intent` like this:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
       b.putStringArray(IMG, thumbUrl);

       Intent passData = new Intent(getContext(), ArticleScreen.class);
       passData.putExtra(TITLE, tv.getText());
       passData.putExtra(ARTICLE, tv2.getText());
       passData.putExtras(b);
       getContext().startActivity(passData);
```

and receive it like this:

## Ion in Receiver Activity

```
private String[] img;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {

        title = extras.getString(NewsAdapter.TITLE);
        article = extras.getString(NewsAdapter.ARTICLE);
        img = extras.getStringArray(NewsAdapter.IMG);

    }

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.articleImg);

    Ion.with(this).load(Arrays.toString(img))
            .withBitmap()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_24dp)
            .intoImageView(iv);
```

But it's gives me that exception

```
 08-20 23:51:23.841  28725-28725/com.mEmoZz.App W/Bundle﹕ Key img expected String[] but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
 08-20 23:51:23.843  28725-28725/com.mEmoZz.App W/Bundle﹕ Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getStringArray(BaseBundle.java:1258)
        at com.mEmoZz.App.ArticleScreen.onCreate(ArticleScreen.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

So what to do right now?

**Sorry for that messy problem but am just a beginner and that's my first time to deal with apps like that.**

Comment: Do you need the whole array in the second activity? or just one one item in that array?

Comment: All what i need that when i tap on any `row` in the `ListView` i got the image on it and display it in the other `activity`, and yes i need one item every time that refers to the clicked `ListView` position.

Comment: Then just pass that item as a regular String. Don't pass the whole array.

Comment: If you mean pass the position of every element in the `array` i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the url of the image related to the row being clicked. DO NOT pass the whole array:

```
//In the Sender:
passData.putExtra(IMG, thumbUrl[position]);

//In the Receiver
String img = extras.getString(NewsAdapter.IMG);
```